# Get Signal Strength from windows CE device using OpenNETCF / C#

Tags: c#, signal-strength, motorola-emdk, opennetcf

I'm already serach the whole internet abut this probelm but with no good result.

I need get signal strength in c# using OpenNETCF.

I tried with this code:

```
            string x = "";
            var adapters = OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.WirelessNetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (WirelessNetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
                x = adapter.SignalStrength.Decibels.ToString();
            label1.Text = x;
```

Visual Studio don't throw any error, but when i run the device show me:„Invalid Cast Exception” :/

**Edit**

Stacktrace:

```
MYapp OpenNETCF.exe InvalidCastException at
MYapp_OpenNETCF.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam) at
System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam) at
Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain) at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm) at
MYapp_OpenNETCF.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Are you able to pinpoint which line is throwing? Can you try breaking `adapter.SignalStrength.Decibels.ToString()` down into multiple statements maybe to isolate?

Comment: I'll tried but only right know VS2008  doesn't throw any errors. So isolate this give me nothing.

Comment: Maybe wrap in a `try/catch` and expose the stacktrace manually somehow

Comment: If I run debugging on visual studio and open emulator it's nothing happen. Just show me empty value, this is normal because application must be running on real device. Then if i put my code to try/catch then and runing on my device, show me only "InvalidCastException"

Comment: In your `catch` you have access to the `Exception`, and from that you should be able to put up a dialog of your own with the `StackTrace` or similar.

Comment: MYapp OpenNETCF.exe
InvalidCastException

   at MYapp_OpenNETCF.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at MYapp_OpenNETCF.Program.Main()